# send data (POST Method) from local to server, by cURL the server reveive EMPTY RECORD

Tags: php, curl

i send data to server from pc local through this form :

```
<form method="post" action="proses.php">
<input type="hidden" name="id"><br>
Tanggal <input type="text" name="tgl"><br>
Pesan <textarea name="isi" cols="29" rows="5"></textarea> <br>
Nomor Hp <input type="text" name="nope"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> </form>
```

and this is code proses.php

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$tgl = $_POST['tgl'];
$isi = $_POST['isi']; $nope= $_POST['nope'];


$curlHandle = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://adibiken.com/SEM/kir.php');
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=".$id."&amp;tgl=".$tgl."&amp;isi=".$isi."&amp;nope=".$nope);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_exec($curlHandle);
curl_close($curlHandle); ?>
```

this is code for kir.php ( in server )

```
<?php $id = $_POST['id']; $tgl = $_POST['tgl']; $isi = $_POST['isi']; $nope = $_POST['nope'];
$quer = "INSERT INTO `adibiken_sem`.`inbox` (`id`,`tgl` ,`isi` ,`nope`)VALUES ( '$id','$tgl', '$isi', '$nope')";
mysql_query($quer); ?>
```

**PROBLEM : data are have been successful SENDING with EMPTY RECORD IN DATBASE SERVER...**
need help please

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the problem but for sure

```
VALUES ( '$id','$tgl', '$isi', '$nope')"
```

should be

```
VALUES ( '".$id."','".$tgl."', '".$isi."', '".$nope."')"
```

Comment: thank's for attention mr.coslu
 but,,still, doesn't work mr.Coslu

Comment: isn't php returning any error? Are you connecting to the db? I don't see the code there but you need also a mysql_connect(  ); and mysql_select_db();

Comment: Are you connecting to the db? 
yes i am mr.coslu, 

connecting to database is ok mr.coslu i already check it.

Answer (score 0):

In file "proses.php" try using "&" instead of "&amp;". Also in file kir.php ( in server ) run print_r($_POST) or log the whole array somewhere to chceck if you are recieving the correct variable names.

Comment: i'm so sory mr.baracudafish,

i don't understand how to make it,

could u give a sample code like that?

Comment: After you Insert into the DB on the server, do/write/insert `print_r($_POST);`. Then print the curl output on the local PC.

Or run `file_put_contents("my_output_file_name.log",print_r($_POST, true));` on the server after you insert into the DB.

Comment: dear mr.baracudafish,

result of file "my_output_file_name.log "

Array
(
    [id] => 
    [amp;tgl] => 
    [amp;isi] => hahahah
    [amp;nope] => 5555555
)


but,,the data still EMPTY RECORD mr,,

Comment: Well, as you can hopefully see you are receiving wrong variable names (post array keys) on the server. Try to do the same thing `file_put_contents("my_output_file_name.log",print_r($_POST, true));` on the local PC before you send it with curl to see if you are receiving any good values from the form on the local PC.

Answer (score 0):

use the http_build_query(...) to form postfields from array.

```
$request = http_build_query($_POST);
...
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$request)
```

If you getting correct values in $_POST array then something is wrong with your SQL syntax.  You can try to execute your query in phpMyAdmin or something else and debug it.
It might happen that MySQL fires an error, but you could not see it. You can get any output from kir.php including error messages (it is enabled on your server):

```
$curResponse = curl_exec($curlHandle);
echo $curResponse;
```

Comment: dear mr.ActivationCloud.
i'm so sory mr.ActivationCloud, i don't understand how to make it,
could u give me a sample code like that?